# Jest test runs - Cannot find module error

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I have been working on a React Typescript repo and have been running into an annoying issue where in jest is not able to resolve imports relative to root dir.

```
 Cannot find module '~lib/dates' from 'utils.ts'
```

And this how the import looks like in the component / utils

```
import { abc } from '~lib/dates';   // this fails to run
```

If I change this to a relative path jest test runs works as expected

```
import { abc } from '../../lib/dates';   // this runs as expected
```

The same path work for some other directories and I am a bit stumped

```
import { xyz } from '~components/home/constants';   // jest resolves it
import { abc } from '~lib/dates';                     // ERR
```

I tried including `moduleNameWrapper` in the jestConfig to see if it jest can resolve the imports correctly but it did not help.

**package.json**

```
"jest": {
   ...

   "moduleNameWrapper": {
      "^~(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    }
}
```

I could for sure update the VS code setting so that auto imports are resolved relatively to the file and not with the root dir but this has been bugging me for a while. It would be great if anyone has any pointers on how best to resolve this.

I am on a monorepo with the following directory structure

```
repo
  server
  client
    src
       components
       lib
       utils
    package.json
```

Comment: What does your repo structure look like?

Comment: What transpiler are you using? Babel or Tsc?

Comment: I am using a mono repo with babel as a transpiler. Will update the post with the directory structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation looks right. But it looks like the option `moduleNameWrapper` was the wrong option, it's supposed to be `moduleNameMapper`.

I also have an example as same as you which also uses babel as transplier, it works fine as I added `moduleNameMapper`. Here is the my example:

Jest configuration:

https://github.com/tmhao2005/lerna-demo/blob/master/packages/share/jest.config.js

Here is the file for testing:

https://github.com/tmhao2005/lerna-demo/blob/master/packages/helper/src/index.ts
https://github.com/tmhao2005/lerna-demo/blob/master/packages/helper/src/index.test.ts

Comment: What was I thinking. I was totally overlooking the API and that never crossed my mind. Tried after updated the option name and it works. Thanks a ton !

Comment: accepted answer, whose github links no longer exists. Great.

Answer (score 1):

forget the `~` character;

first [define root directory](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulepaths-arraystring) to jest (i.e. `src/`);

then import your stuff from that root directory; (e.g. `import { abc } from 'lib/dates'`)

by the way you can always import your stuff from default root without any configuration like this: `import { abc } from 'src/lib/dates'`

further read if you are using create-react-app [jest absolute import](https://blog.shovonhasan.com/using-absolute-imports-with-jest-in-create-react-app/)

Comment: The roots directory is already defined in the repo which is `./src`, in this case the client directory. 

Its not about importing, but rather how to resolve auto imports to work with an IDE. It is a pain to go over all the files and then update the imports. Also we spun the repo off without using `create-react-app`

Comment: @Sushanth-- if root directory is define correctly for jest, then you can jump to step 2 directly

Comment: The thing is, if it was a personal project I would not mind doing it. But with other team members in the team it cant really be a personal preference. Pretty sure it would work but this not the answer I am really looking for. 
One more major point is that, it is a pain to go ahead and update around 400 different files

Comment: @Sushanth-- hmm yeah that would be impractical to replace them manually. by the way If you didn't find the answer you were looking for, try replacing `'~` with `src/` in import urls with editors search and replace functionality, if root directory set properly, this change won't break anything.