# NestJS Jest cannot find module with absolute path

Tags: node.js, jestjs, nestjs, ts-jest

I have a quite new NestJS application. I'm trying to run unit tests, but they keep failing due to 'cannot find module..' when using absolute paths ("src/users/..."), but works when using relative paths ("./users/.."). Is there anything wrong with my configuration here?

Jest setup in package.json:

```
"jest": {
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "json",
    "ts"
  ],
  "rootDir": "src",
  "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
  "testEnvironment": "node"
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your question similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63709973/jest-test-runs-cannot-find-module-error/63716954#63716954?

Answer (score 45):

I had the same issue, the problem was the default jest configuration created by Nestjs.

I changed `"rootDir": "src"` to `"rootDir": "./"` and add `"modulePaths": ['<rootDir>']`.

Finaly, my jest configuration looks like this:

```
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'ts'],
  rootDir: './',
  modulePaths: ['<rootDir>'],
  testRegex: 'spec.ts$',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(t|j)s$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  coverageDirectory: './coverage',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
```

If you have some relative paths to your config you will probably have to update them because your `rootDir` is not `src` anymore.

You can even remove `rootDir` is you setup the jest config in `package.json` or if the config file is located at the root of your project, as explained in the doc: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#rootdir-string

And if you want read about `modulePaths`: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulepaths-arraystring

Hope it will also work for you.

Comment: Note that this configuration can be found in `package.json`. Most of the pre-configured configuration of jest by Nest is the same. For me, I only had to alter the `rootDir` and add `modulePaths` as depicted above to make it work.

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: If you have something like `@shared` or anything like `@`, check `moduleNameMapper` to make it resolve that.

Comment: That modulePaths is definitely missing in the default jest conf, that helped a lot, thanks !

Answer (score 36):

---

I spent a lot of time searching and figuring this problem out.

---

#### My Specific Issue

I faced this issue when running e2e tests with `NestJS`. I set up the absolute path from the root of the project. Here is my `tsconfig.json`.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}
```

---

### Here is what solved my problem.

add `moduleDirectories: ['<rootDir>/../', 'node_modules']` to `test/jest-e2e.config.js`.

working `test/jest-e2e.config.js`

```json
{
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'ts'],
  rootDir: '.',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testRegex: '.e2e-spec.ts$',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(t|j)s$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  moduleDirectories: ['<rootDir>/../', 'node_modules'],
};
```

> NOTE:
> [`moduleDirectories`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#moduledirectories-arraystring) options should be paths relative to the jest confi g file, it is necessary to start you path from `<rootDir>` and go back as needed.
> For details of this visit https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/5522#issuecomment-714592183

---

Here is the link to my repo if you want to have a look at it.
https://github.com/mabdullahadeel/nest-bookmarker

---

Comment: Don't understand why the node_modules is required but it worked. Thank you.

Comment: thanks a lot. the '<rootDir>/../' was missing from my configs

Answer (score 13):

You need to configure how jest resolves module paths by configuring the [moduleNameMapper](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring).

package.json

```
    {  
      "jest": {
                // ...
        "rootDir": "src",
        "moduleNameMapper": {
          "^src/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1"
        },
      }
    }
```

Comment: Worked for me - still doesn't seem to be fixed in the NestJS bootstrap configuration... :-/

Answer (score 6):

in my case the

```
"moduleDirectories": ["<rootDir>/../", "node_modules"]
```

needed to be specified in the /test/jest-e2e.json,
that fixed the issue

Comment: I just met the same issue. This answer did solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are missing the `rootDir` in your `tsconfig.json`

If you want to `import { ... } from 'src/...`, the `rootDir` needs to be equal to `./`.

Check this example:

```
{
"moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "json",
    "js"
],
"rootDir": "./",
"testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
"collectCoverageFrom": ["**/*.ts", "!**/node_modules/**"],
"coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
"coverageReporters": ["html", "text", "text-summary"],
"preset": "ts-jest",}



  "compilerOptions": {
  "module": "commonjs",
  "declaration": true,
  "removeComments": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "target": "es2017",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "outDir": "./dist",
  "rootDir": "./",
  "baseUrl": "./",
  "incremental": true
}
```

Comment: Still, not working