# VSCode debugger not working with src/ prefixed import paths

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, vscode-debugger, tsconfig

I have `Nest.js` app with configured `launch.json` and when I start debugging, it fails with error saying that it can't find module, when import path starts with `'src/'`, for example:

This will fail with the error `Error: Cannot find module 'src/user/module'`:

```
import { UserModule } from 'src/user/user.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ...
    UserModule,
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This will work:

```
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ...
    UserModule,
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here's my `launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configureOptions": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug Nest",
      "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/src/main.ts"],
      "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy", "-r", "ts-node/register"],
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "console": "externalTerminal"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able to debug the services in our project we needed to change a setting in VS Code:

Open `Code -> Preferences -> Settings`

Search for `JavaScript: Auto Attach Filter` and set it to `Always`

We did not need to change the `launch.json`

Also, In your jest properties which are probably located in the `package.json` (assuming you generated the nest project automatically). You will need to change the `rootDir` property:

from

`rootDir: 'src',`

to

`rootDir: './',`

This should allow it to work the full path instead of the relative path

see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64028100/nestjs-jest-cannot-find-module-with-absolute-path) for further details

Comment: The above answer worked perfectly for me.  This person is a genius.

Comment: Also, in VSCode, you can force the QuickFix to give you relative paths by going into Settings and searching for "typescript". 
Then look for "Import Module Specifier" and set it to "relative".